Do I Need Clear Coat for Small Chip/Scratch/Gouge Repair?
I had some scratches, chips, and a couple deeper/wider gouges from a side-swipe incident that I decided to have repaired...my car is ~15 years-old so I was a little ambivalent, but finally decided the cost was worth the gain.
I had a mobile chip/scratch service come and address...Overall it is an OK job, especially considering the cost saving vs. an auto body shop, and fact my car is older.  The 7 or 8 spots that were repaired, including the two ~(1" x 1") gouges, looked fine to my layman's eye, and so that was good enough for me.
It subsequently occurred to me that the job was finished in a less time than I would have thought, so I contacted the guy and asked if the gouges in particular were all primed, painted, and had a clearcoat applied.  He said he doesn't use a clearcoat for this size of repair as it is a challenge to feather into the rest of the paint.
Three questions:
1) Do I need a clearcoat on things of this size?  i.e. what's the downside, if any, of not having?
2) Paint was applied three days ago at time I am writing this and has likely cured to the point that applying a clearcoat now may be problematic.  Is it important enough that I should do what it takes, incl light scuff sanding and applying, or even re-paint, then clearcoat?
3) I have a ceramic coating applied every two years or so (as well as reasonably frequent maintenance car washes and periodic waxing).  Is simply having a ceramic coating applied, including where new paint is, sufficient to protect the paint in those places?
